# Simulating separation forces amount n bodies

Tags: performance, algorithm, simulation, physics

I'm writing a simulation for little creatures that walk around the screen. One issue I'm having is that they'll get too close sometimes - I figure that one way to solve this is to have a certain threshold distance, and when any two creatures get closer than this distance, a force will push them apart.

Before I implement this, however, I was wondering if there are any known algorithms for this *besides* the brute force [image] solution.

I've been researching a few different algorithms, and one of note was the Barnes-Hut algorithm, which runs in [image] time - however, I'm not sure if this would work for this problem.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Barnes-Hut and variations are the common way to do this, but I would not implement the full algorithm for your use case because it seems overkill. I would probably just divide the plane into a square grid, say 20 x 20, and maintain a set for each cell with all the creatures currently located within the cell. Then for each creature just look into its cell and the 8 (or 5 at the sides or 3 in the corners) neighboring cells and use a force that drops to zero within the length of one cell.

There is an obvious trade-off - a finer grid means less pairs of creatures to consider but you will then have to move them from cell to cell more often. A cell length smaller than the range of the force is useless because you will not only have to consider the 8 neighbors but cells beyond them that are within the range of the force.

Comment: Does this grid approach have a particular name, or are there any theories about optimal grid size?

Comment: On the topic of overkill - would the Barnes-Hut algorithm take *longer* for a smaller number of bodies than brute-forcing (i.e. 10 bodies)?

Comment: @fibonatic I just made the grid thing up, no idea if it has a name. I first wanted to suggest using a quadtree but then I thought that it might still be overkill. Assuming a somewhat uniform distribution of objects `cells[object.X / cellSize, object.Y / cellSize]` is such a simple solution that you need really good reasons - a *lot* of objects and very non-uniform distribution - to justify the complexity of using some tree structure.

Comment: @Sim I don't know for sure but my intuition is that the naive algorithm can outperform Barnes-Hut maybe up to 50, 100 maybe even 500 objects but that's really hard to guess. But I am pretty confident that it will be slower for 10 objects. Space partitioning really excels for large collection of objects where naive solutions or not viable at all - thousands, millions and tens of millions of objects.

Comment: By the way, I think the more important idea is to limit the range of the force. Barnes-Hut approximates forces between all objects but if you are not simulating a physical force field and you can just declare that the force is zero after some distance you can just ignore a lot of objects. Partitioning the space is then just a mean to figure out for which objects the force might be non-zero and which objects you can simply ignore because they are to far away.

Answer (score 2):

Gridding out your bodies into a tree structure, use a quadtree for 2D and octree for 3D.
The idea behind `O(n log n)` algorithms is to make `log n` comparisons for every body instead of `n` comparisons. If your bodies are clustered into groups, you can compute the average mass and position of a cluster. Rather than having a force from each of the bodies in that group acting on a body, a single combined force of an equivalent pseudo body acts on another body. I believe this is the idea behind Barnes-Hut.

You will need a fast algorithm to identify your clusters, determine when you can sacrifice simulation accuracy for speed (it may be okay to group Jupiter and its moons as a single pseudo-body to calculate the gravitational force on Earth. It probably isn't okay to group Jupiter and Saturn as a single pseudo-body to calculate the gravitational force on Earth)

The larger you let your clusters get, the less accuracy you have. However, larger clusters also means fewer body-body comparisons that need to make. You may also want to optimize clustering that can be reused for other bodies. Grouping all of the inner planets with the Sun may be okay to compute forces on all outer solar system bodies.

Start with the naive `O(n^2)` approach first before you venture into the complex `O(n log n)` implementations. When you're ready, there's a lot of great literature on the web about n-body simulations.